# Django form ChoiceField allow dynamic choices through jquery

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, django-validation

I have a django form with the field -

```
section = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('', '---'),), required=False)
```

The choices are dynamically generated in jquery, the relevant code being -

```
var html = '<option value="">---</option>';
for (var i=0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    section = sections[i];
    html += '<option value="'+section+'">'+section+'</option>'
}
$("#id_section").html(html)
```

Everything works fine. However, when I try to submit the form it says `Select a valid choice. (selected_option) is not one of the choices`. Is there any way to circumvent this error apart from removing `form.is_valid()`? I thought `required=False` would be enough.

I know there are other ways to code this part but a direct solution to this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Well since these options are not in the `choices` of your `ChoiceField`, the `ChoiceField` will of course reject these.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So you're saying I should not use `ChoiceField` since it cannot work that way?

Comment: exactly what are the `sections`? Why do you not inject the sections in the `ChoiceField`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem They are dynamically generated through other form fields and ajax requests. It's quite complicated but this is the main part

Comment: You should be able to use CharField and just write the html as a Select.

Comment: @HenryM ended up removing the field itself and just creating all the field html through js. But yeah your method should work